# Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 183)

Tags: linux, cross-compiling, elf

This used to work before. I don't know what changed, the thing is I can't run anymore. I'm cross-compiling for an aarch64 architecture with ARM cpu's, using Ubuntu 16.04 x86-64.

This is what I'm running to configure:

> ./configure --host=aarch64-linux-gnu --prefix=/data/data/papi/independent --exec-prefix=/data/data/papi/dependent --with-static-lib=yes --with-shared-lib=no --with-static-tools --with-arch=aarch64 --with-CPU=arm --with-ffsll --with-walltimer=cycle --with-tls=__thread --with-virtualtimer=clock_cputime_id --with-perf-events

Logs from running configure:

```
checking for architecture... aarch64
checking for OS... linux
checking for OS version... 4.15.0-29-generic
checking for perf_event workaround level... autodetect
checking for if MIC should be used... no
checking for aarch64-linux-gnu-xlc... no
checking for aarch64-linux-gnu-icc... no
checking for aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc... aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... yes
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for aarch64-linux-gnu-xlf... no
checking for aarch64-linux-gnu-ifort... no
checking for aarch64-linux-gnu-gfortran... no
checking for aarch64-linux-gnu-f95... no
checking for aarch64-linux-gnu-f90... no
checking for aarch64-linux-gnu-f77... no
checking for xlf... no
checking for ifort... no
checking for gfortran... gfortran
configure: WARNING: using cross tools not prefixed with host triplet
checking whether we are using the GNU Fortran 77 compiler... yes
checking whether gfortran accepts -g... yes
checking for mpicc... mpicc
checking for gawk... gawk
checking how to run the C preprocessor... aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -E
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for aarch64-linux-gnu-ranlib... aarch64-linux-gnu-ranlib
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking minix/config.h usability... no
checking minix/config.h presence... no
checking for minix/config.h... no
checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... yes
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking for inline... inline
checking whether time.h and sys/time.h may both be included... yes
checking sys/time.h usability... yes
checking sys/time.h presence... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking c_asm.h usability... no
checking c_asm.h presence... no
checking for c_asm.h... no
checking intrinsics.h usability... no
checking intrinsics.h presence... no
checking for intrinsics.h... no
checking mach/mach_time.h usability... no
checking mach/mach_time.h presence... no
checking for mach/mach_time.h... no
checking sched.h usability... yes
checking sched.h presence... yes
checking for sched.h... yes
checking for gethrtime... no
checking for read_real_time... no
checking for time_base_to_time... no
checking for clock_gettime... yes
checking for mach_absolute_time... no
checking for sched_getcpu... yes
checking for dlopen and dlerror symbols in base system... not found
checking for dlopen and dlerror symbols in -ldl... found
checking for native compiler for header generation... gcc
checking for debug build... 
checking for -Wno-override-init... 1
checking for CPU type... arm
forcing use of pthread mutexes... 
checking for ffsll... yes
checking for working gettid... no
checking for working syscall(SYS_gettid)... yes
checking for which real time clock to use... cycle
checking for high performance thread local storage... __thread
checking for which virtual timer to use... clock_cputime_id
checking for static user preset events... no
checking for static PAPI preset events... yes
checking for whether to build static library... yes
checking for whether to build shared library... no
checking for static compile of tests and utilities... yes
checking for linking with papi shared library of tests and utilities... no
checking platform... linux-pe
checking for components to build... perf_event perf_event_uncore
checking for PAPI event CSV filename to use... papi_events.csv
configure: Compiling genpapifdef with gcc because cross compiling
configure: Generating fpapi.h
configure: Generating f77papi.h
configure: Generating f90papi.h
configure: Rules.pfm4_pe will be included in the generated Makefile
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating papi.pc
config.status: creating components/Makefile_comp_tests.target
config.status: creating testlib/Makefile.target
config.status: creating utils/Makefile.target
config.status: creating ctests/Makefile.target
config.status: creating ftests/Makefile.target
config.status: creating validation_tests/Makefile.target
config.status: creating config.h
```

After running make:

(...)

```
mpicc -I../testlib -I../validation_tests -I.. -I.  -g -Wextra -DUSE_PTHREAD_MUTEXES  -Wall -O1  first.c ../testlib/libtestlib.a ../testlib/do_loops.o ../libpapi.a -ldl -static -o mpifirst 
/usr/bin/ld: ../testlib/libtestlib.a(test_utils.o): Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 183)
/usr/bin/ld: ../testlib/libtestlib.a(test_utils.o): Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 183)
/usr/bin/ld: ../testlib/libtestlib.a(test_utils.o): Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 183)
/usr/bin/ld: ../testlib/libtestlib.a(test_utils.o): Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 183)
/usr/bin/ld: ../testlib/libtestlib.a(test_utils.o): Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 183)
/usr/bin/ld: ../testlib/libtestlib.a(test_utils.o): Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 183)
../testlib/libtestlib.a: error adding symbols: File in wrong format
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile.recipies:230: recipe for target 'mpifirst' failed
make[2]: *** [mpifirst] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/lfpm1993/Desktop/papi/src/ctests'
Makefile.inc:240: recipe for target 'ctests' failed
make[1]: *** [ctests] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/lfpm1993/Desktop/papi/src'
Rules.pfm4_pe:42: recipe for target 'libpfm4/lib/libpfm.a' failed
make: *** [libpfm4/lib/libpfm.a] Error 2
```

file test_utils.o gives:

> test_utils.o: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped

It looks to me that it is the right type for the file I'm trying to build.

Any clues on how to solve it?

Thanks,
Luís

Comment: Makefile.recipies:230: recipe for target 'mpifirst' failed   

Corresponds to this line of the Makefile:   

mpifirst: mpifirst.c $(TESTLIB) $(DOLOOPS) $(PAPILIB)
 $(MPICC) $(INCLUDE) $(MPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(TOPTFLAGS) first.c $(TESTLIB) $(DOLOOPS) $(PAPILIB) $(LDFLAGS) -o mpifirst -lpthread

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mpicc -I../testlib ...  first.c ../testlib/libtestlib.a ...
/usr/bin/ld: ../testlib/libtestlib.a(test_utils.o): Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 183)
```

This is invoking the wrong linker (system linker), and most likely also invoking the wrong compiler to compile `first.c`.

What happens when you run"

```
mpicc -c  -I../testlib -I../validation_tests -I.. -I.  -DUSE_PTHREAD_MUTEXES first.c
file first.o
```

I bet it says `ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped`, which would explain your problem: your `libtestlib.a` is compiled for desired architecture, but your main program is not.

I can reproduce this exact error message by trying to link `x86_64` `foo.o` with a library of `aarch64` objects.

> This used to work before.

Possibly you have modified `PATH` before, such that `mpicc` found `gcc` for target. And how you've neglected to set the `PATH` appropriately.

(`Makefile`s that depend on `PATH` and other environment variables are the worst -- they work in one shell, but not in another.)

Comment: Employed Russian your anwer was really enlightening and it saved me a lot of time.

>What happens when you run?
>mpicc -c  -I../testlib -I../validation_tests -I.. -I.  -DUSE_PTHREAD_MUTEXES first.c
>file first.o
>I bet it says ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped

You are absolutely right, that was the output.

Was curious about mpicc so I checked it out:
    $ mpicc --print-multiarch
    x86_64-linux-gnu

I don't really know how to change the triplet, but I will look into that. Either way, I'm extremely grateful, thanks :)